# Get the path of file from Thymeleaf to controller

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have to get some data from Excel file, and when trying to test i am setting the path manually (It works !).
Now i want to create a page and select the file with button to get the path.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mypage")
public String fct(Model md) throws Exception{
    File excel=new File("pathofmyfile/name.xls");//here the path
    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(excel);
    HSSFWorkbook wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet ws=wb.getSheet("Feuil1");//to read first sheet only 

    int nbligne=ws.getLastRowNum()+1;//to get number of line not empty

    String[] cotes=new String[nbligne];

    for(int i =0;i<nbligne;i++) {
        HSSFRow ligne= ws.getRow(i);
        HSSFCell cell= ligne.getCell(0);
        cotes[i]= cell.toString().substring(cell.toString().lastIndexOf("=") + 1);

        System.out.println(cotes[i]);
    }

    return "mypage";
}
```

Now i want a suggestion from you or an example of html page how to pass the path of excel from html to controller

Comment: Umm do you want to upload file or let user select path from server (that is what yo are doing now).You will have to make POST with required path as data (or GET, depends on context, but will work in both cases - its just matter of "standards")

Comment: Yes just the path of the file like i am doing manually

Comment: Post it then or use it as query parameter. Markup for either way will look just the same.